# in app update for ios apps without redirecting to app store or itunes

Tags: ios, swift

The below code redirects me to app store but it should not happen. The app should get updated within the app without redirecting to app store or itunes.
    // Function to check for the app version

```
    func isUpdateAvailable() throws -> Bool {
                    guard let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary,
                        let currentVersion = info["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String,
                        let identifier = info["CFBundleIdentifier"] as? String,
                        let url = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/in/lookup?bundleId=\(identifier)") else {
                            throw VersionError.invalidBundleInfo
                    }
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                    guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments]) as? [String: Any] else {
                        throw VersionError.invalidResponse
                    }
                    if let result = (json["results"] as? [Any])?.first as? [String: Any],
                        let version = result["version"] as? String {
                        print("version in app store", version,currentVersion);

                        return version != currentVersion
                    }
                    throw VersionError.invalidResponse
                }

    // Function to show alert for 

    func popuplateAppUpdateDialogue(in vc: UIViewController,
                                                title: String?,
                                                message: String,
                                                for appleId: String){
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let updateBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style: .default) { (_) in
                        AppUtils.shared.openAppOnAppStore(appleId: appleId)
                    }

    // Below is the AppUtils function which I used in my code

    func openAppOnAppStore(appleId: String){
                    let appStoreLink: String = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id\(appleId)"
                    if let url = URL(string: appStoreLink) {
                        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil
                        } else {
                            // Earlier versions
                            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
                                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Why do you think this should not happen? If it is redirecting you to app store, it's working exactly as it should be.

Comment: There is no way to programatically fire a "under the hood" / background update for an app. Either the user must tap "Update" in the App Store themselves, or have "Automatic updates" enabled and wait for iOS to fetch and install the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full iOS applications cannot be updated from within the application itself, only through the app store. Also you have no say or control as a developer whether your user updates the application or not. Short of blocking them from using it by some internal logic.

There are advanced techniques out there that allow you to update certain aspects of the application's business logic, but that's beyond the scope of this question.